# VSCode | Basic compiling issues with Maven

Tags: java, maven, persistence

This is my first Java project using Maven (Jakarta and PostgreSQL dependencies) in which I am struggling with many basic compiling issues. I am also using the newest VSCode as an editor.

**First issue**

The terminal tries to find `Main.java` at '*...\Projeto-POO-2022.2*' when it should actually access '*...\Projeto-POO-2022.2\javarental\src\main\java\poo*' where the file currently lies.

I have already tried manually setting up `terminal.integrated.cwd` to access the right path with no success.

**Second issue**

Even using *'cd javarental\src\main\java\poo'* to access the right path and then running the project with *'javac Main.java'* the following errors come up:

```
Main.java:3: error: package jakarta.persistence does not exist
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
                          ^
Main.java:4: error: package jakarta.persistence does not exist
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
                          ^
Main.java:5: error: package jakarta.persistence does not exist
import jakarta.persistence.Persistence;
                          ^
Main.java:7: error: package poo.models does not exist
import poo.models.Usuario;
                 ^
Main.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
        Usuario user = new Usuario();
        ^
  symbol:   class Usuario
  location: class Main
Main.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
        Usuario user = new Usuario();
                           ^
  symbol:   class Usuario
  location: class Main
Main.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("default");
        ^
  symbol:   class EntityManagerFactory
  location: class Main
Main.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("default");
                                   ^
  symbol:   variable Persistence
  location: class Main
Main.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        ^
  symbol:   class EntityManager
  location: class Main
9 errors
```

For addition, this is the section of code `Main.java`:

```
package poo;

import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import jakarta.persistence.Persistence;
import poo.models.Usuario;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Usuario user = new Usuario();
        user.setEmail("teste@teste.com");
        user.setNomeUsuario("user_3");
        user.setNome("User");
        user.setSenha("senha");
        user.setCpf(123);


        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("default");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    
        em.close();
    }
}
```

And this is my `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>poo</groupId>
  <artifactId>javarental</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>javarental</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>42.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Don't know if it has something to do with but I've imported and synced this project straight from GitHub. I've also tried rebuilding it a few times with no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I got it working through the following steps:

1. Delete the project folder;
2. Remove any invalid characters from the new project folder path;
3. Create a new folder;
4. Clone once again the repository from GitHub into the new folder.

Answer (score 1):

For the first problem, I have no idea.
For the second problem, it's possible that your `pom.xml` has the wrong dependencies.

Also, I love the package name. (poo)

Comment: Thanks. Somehow I got it working through the following steps:

Delete the project folder;
Remove any invalid characters from the new project folder path;
Create a new folder;
Clone once again the repository from GitHub.